# E/Volley: [3997] NetworkDispatcher.processRequest: Unhandled exception java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-volley, jsonobjectrequest

Can someone please explain this Android Volley error and if possible a solution for me.
Thank you in advance.

```
E/Volley: [3997] NetworkDispatcher.processRequest: Unhandled exception java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference
                                                                          java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference
                                                                              at java.net.URLEncoder.encode(URLEncoder.java:205)
                                                                              at com.android.volley.Request.encodeParameters(Request.java:491)
                                                                              at com.android.volley.Request.getBody(Request.java:477)
                                                                              at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.addBodyIfExists(HurlStack.java:245)
                                                                              at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.setConnectionParametersForRequest(HurlStack.java:219)
                                                                              at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.executeRequest(HurlStack.java:97)
                                                                              at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:131)
                                                                              at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.processRequest(NetworkDispatcher.java:120)
                                                                              at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:87)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NullPointerException
```

means that some of your variables is `null` at run time. The problem is not in the Volley library.

Comment: thanks yes i check and some of my variables are null at runtime even when i assign a value to it in code.Is there anyway to fix this

Comment: It depends on your specific case. The simplest way is to initialize your variables (objects) like this: MyObject myObject = new Object(); Or is its int or String just set the value at initialization point like this: int x = 0; or String str = "";